# Unable to refresh jQuery weekcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, refresh

I am using jQuery weekcalendar to create a webbased calender with appointments. According to the [docs](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/Public-methods), refreshing the calendar should be easy:

```
$(“#calendar”).weekCalendar(“refresh”); // Refreshes the currently rendered week – if the events are based on a remote data source they will be refetched.
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

When I try to call this code, the calendar does not refresh. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#calendar').weekCalendar('refresh');
```

Comment: Show your code for initializing the weekcalendar with the `data:` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my events and users using JSON from a database. I exported the needed steps to a function that gets the `events`, `users` and refreshes the `eventData1`.

After this step, the normal refresh command did the job:

```
 getEvents();
 $("#calendar").weekCalendar("refresh");
```